# Can't get world position from reverse Z buffer

Tags: opengl, shaders, rendering, matrix, deferred-rendering

I'm using [this solution](https://nlguillemot.wordpress.com/2016/12/07/reversed-z-in-opengl/) to render using a reversed Z buffer.

This looks fine and completely fixes all my z-fighting, but it breaks what I use in shader to derive the world position from the depth for various purposes such as deferred lighting and fog (it has worked for a regular projection matrix):

```
vec4 screenSpacePosition = vec4(texcoord * 2.0 - 1.0, depth * 2.0 - 1.0, 1);
vec4 worldSpacePosition = invProjView  * screenSpacePosition;
vec3 finalPosition = worldSpacePosition.xyz / worldSpacePosition.w;
return finalPosition;
```

I've thought that this was due to this using a single view projection matrix, so I've also tried this:

```
vec4 clipSpacePosition = vec4(texcoord * 2.0 - 1.0, depth * 2.0 - 1.0, 1.0);
vec4 viewSpacePosition = invProj * clipSpacePosition;
viewSpacePosition /= viewSpacePosition.w;
vec4 worldSpacePosition = invView * viewSpacePosition;
return worldSpacePosition.xyz;
```

That must be suboptimal performance wise, but it doesn't work either anyway. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Sometimes z buffers can be scaled to give higher resolution for closer objects, have you checked for this?